# Manipulating nested data

Tags: r, nested, data-manipulation

I am new to r and I am having some trouble manipulating the data in the way I need it for my analysis. I would be grateful if anyone could help.

my data looks something like this:

```
df<- data.frame("Reporter" = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA","USA"),
"Partner" = c( "EU", "EU","EU","EU", "EU","EU"), 
"Product cat." = c("1", "11", "111", "122", "12", "2"), 
"Year" = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970), 
"trade value" = c( 100, 50, 25, 5, 40, 220), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I have multiple country-year observations with data on trade about trade. The vector **product. cat** indicates what kind of commodity is exported. **The more digits the *product. cat* has, the more the trade  information is disaggregated**. For example product cat. 111 (eg. apple) and 112 (e.g. bananas) are sub-product categories of product category 11 (e.g. fruit). Product category 11 is a subcategory of food (product cat.1).

To do my analysis I need that all the values are reported at the most disaggregated possible level - i.e. I need all the data to have the most number of digit possible.

My problem is that for some country-year observation I have data reported only at the higher level of aggregation. For instance, consider the following list of product cat. as a comparison for the one in the example.

```
ls.prod.cat<- data.frame(
  "Product cat." = c("1", "11", "111", "122", "12","121","122","2","21","22","211"), 
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In the example, I have data reported at the 2 digit level (12) that could be reported at the 3 digit level (121, 122). 
What I would like to do is to find a way to individuate all the data only reported at a higher level of aggregation (e.g. like 12) and change their product cat. adding an "m" to the end. 
Hence after manipulation the product cat. 12 should become **12m**.

Similarly for higher levels of aggregation. 
For instance, when data is reported only at the first digit of product cat. digit I would like to have data that adds two "mm" at the end of product cat. to reflect that data is reported only at the first level of aggregation. For instance, in my df, this means that data that has product cat. 2 should become product cat. **2mm**

---- UPDATE ---

In sum, I am looking for a way to automatically individuate the rows where data is **exclusively** reported at the higher level of aggregation and to those rows change the product cat. name adding the corresponding numbers of m. Only for the data for which I have only data at a higher level of aggregation should include "m"s. For instance, in the example, I do not want to have 1mm, since I have data at a lower level of aggregation (11,12). Similarly, I do not want to have 11m, because I have data at lower levels of aggregation (111,112). What I would like to have is 12m. as data on 121 and 122 should exist (cfr `ls.prod.cat`) but the data is reported only at a higher level of aggregation (12).

I know that this is a very specific question but I would really appreciate if anyone could help.

---- UPDATE 2---

consider the more sophisticated dataset

```
df3 <- <- data.frame(
"Reporter" = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA","USA", "USA", 
"USA","USA","EU", "EU","EU","EU","EU", "EU","EU","EU","EU", "EU", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA","USA", "USA", "USA","USA"),
"Partner" = c( "EU", "EU","EU","EU", "EU","EU","EU", 
"EU","EU","EU","USA", "USA", "USA","USA","USA", "USA", 
"USA","USA","USA", "USA", "EU", "EU","EU","EU", "EU","EU","EU", 
"EU","EU","EU"), 
"Product cat." = c("1", "11", "111", "112", "12","2", "21","211", "22", 
"3", "1", "11", "111", "112", "2", "21", "211", "212", "22", "221", 
"1", "11", "111", "112", "12","2", "21","211", "22", "3"), 
"Year" = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970,1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 
1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1980, 1980, 
1980, 1980,  1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980, 1980), 
"Val" = c( 100, 50, 25, 5, 40, 200, 170, 170, 30, 220, 190, 190, 120, 
30, 300, 200, 150, 50, 100, 100, 150, 50, 25,25, 100, 300, 120, 100, 
160, 200), 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

when I run the Function fillLevel on my code

`fillLevel <- function(x, width = 3, fill = "m"){  sp <- split(x, substr(x, 1, 1))  sp <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){    n <- nchar(sp[[i]])    if(all(n < 3)){      j <- which(n == max(n))      sp[[i]][j] <- gsub(" ", "m", formatC(sp[[i]][j], width = -3))    }   sp[[i]]  })  unname(unlist(sp))}`

Some strange thing happen
`m.df3 <- df3 %>% mutate(m.prodcat = fillLevel(Product cat.))`
In particular, the `m.prodcat` categories do not correspond to the `product cat.`.
For instance, USA to EU export **changes from product cat. 2 to m.prodcat 1**, from product cat. 21 to m.prodcat 11 and so on. with many other mismatches.

Does anyone know what could be the reason? thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R way of doing what I understand of the question after your comment.
I have created another dataset with two extra rows, in order to have a code that goes up just to the second level of aggregation.

```
df2 <- data.frame("Reporter" = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA","USA", "USA", "USA"),
                 "Partner" = c( "EU", "EU","EU","EU", "EU","EU","EU", "EU"), 
                 "Product cat." = c("1", "11", "111", "122", "12", "2", "3", "31"), 
                 "Year" = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970, 1970), 
                 "trade value" = c( 100, 50, 25, 5, 40, 220, 120, 20), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


fillLevel <- function(x, width = 3, fill = "m"){
  sp <- split(x, substr(x, 1, 1))
  sp <- lapply(seq_along(sp), function(i){
    n <- nchar(sp[[i]])
    if(all(n < 3)){
      j <- which(n == max(n))
      sp[[i]][j] <- gsub(" ", "m", formatC(sp[[i]][j], width = -3))
    }
    sp[[i]]
  })
  unname(unlist(sp))
}

fillLevel(df$Product.cat.)
#[1] "1"   "11"  "111" "122" "12"  "2mm"

fillLevel(df2$Product.cat.)
#[1] "1"   "11"  "111" "122" "12"  "2mm" "3"   "31m"
```

Now assign the function's result to whatever you want, be it a new column or the original one.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, the issue however is that I would like to put the "m" only into those categories that are expressed at a higher level of the hierarchy. For instance, in your results, I have 1mm or 11m, but i do not want this as I already have data disaggregated for this (11,111). my issue is to exactly individuate (and put the "m"s) only to those rows that are reported only at a higher level of aggregation in comparison to my ls.prod.cat. In sum, only product cat. 12 should become 12m and product cat. 2 should become 2mm. would you know how to do this for a big dataset?

Comment: I have written a brief update in my question that may help to clarify what I am trying to do. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @Alessandro See if this is it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is really great and indeed this works very well!

Comment: so playing a bit with your code I realise I am having some problems when applying it to the real data. 1) it does not seem able to individuate all the missing data at the first level of aggregation (also12 should become 12m) 2) it seems to create some mismatch with the more complicated dataset (i have updated my question with a new dataset and problem to illustrate this). Do you have any idea of why this could be? I know I am being very specific but you are really giving me great help with this. Thanks really a lot

Comment: @Alessandro I don't understand why `"12"` should be `"12m"`, isn't it a disaggregation of the previous `"122"`?

Comment: Because should have data on 121 and 122 (e.g. pork meat, and beef) but I only have data on 12 (meat in general). So to reflect the fact that I do not know what kind of meat it is I want to put the "m". The issue is that I have data from multiple countries (and years) and while some report accurately (121 and 122) other only report the general categories (12). I want to be able to individuate (with an "m") the latter countries - or more precisely the product cat. for every country year. I hope this help clarifying the issue. Do let me know if it is still confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `str_pad`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Product.cat. = str_pad(Product.cat., width = 3, pad = "m", side = "right"))
#  Reporter Partner Product.cat. Year trade.value
#1      USA      EU          1mm 1970         100
#2      USA      EU          11m 1970          50
#3      USA      EU          111 1970          25
#4      USA      EU          122 1970           5
#5      USA      EU          12m 1970          40
#6      USA      EU          2mm 1970         220
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, the issue however is that I would like to put the "m" **only** into those categories that are expressed at a higher level of the hierarchy. For instance, in your results, I have 1mm or 11m, but i do not want this as I already have data disaggregated for this (11,111). my issue is to exactly individuate (and put the "m"s) only to those rows that are reported only at a higher level of aggregation in comparison to my ls.prod.cat. In sum, **only product cat. 12 should become 12m and product cat. 2 should become 2mm**. would you know how to do this for a big dataset?

Comment: I have written a brief update in my question that may help to clarify what I am trying to do. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `stri_pad_rigth()` from `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, Product.cat. = stri_pad_right(Product.cat., 3, 'm'))

  Reporter Partner Product.cat. Year trade.value
1      USA      EU          1mm 1970         100
2      USA      EU          11m 1970          50
3      USA      EU          111 1970          25
4      USA      EU          122 1970           5
5      USA      EU          12m 1970          40
6      USA      EU          2mm 1970         220
```

`readr::str_pad()`, under the hood, uses `stringi::stri_pad_*()` functions:

```
> str_pad
function (string, width, side = c("left", "right", "both"), pad = " ") 
{
    side <- match.arg(side)
    switch(side, left = stri_pad_left(string, width, pad = pad), 
        right = stri_pad_right(string, width, pad = pad), both = stri_pad_both(string, 
            width, pad = pad))
}
<bytecode: 0x566a028>
<environment: namespace:stringr>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, the issue however is that I would like to put the "m" only into those categories that are expressed at a higher level of the hierarchy. For instance, in your results, I have 1mm or 11m, but i do not want this as I already have data disaggregated for this (11,111). my issue is to exactly individuate (and put the "m"s) only to those rows that are reported only at a higher level of aggregation in comparison to my ls.prod.cat. In sum, only product cat. 12 should become 12m and product cat. 2 should become 2mm. would you know how to do this for a big dataset?

Comment: I have written a brief update in my question that may help to clarify what I am trying to do. Thank you again for your help.